# How to sync iDevices on Pre Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: idevices

Is there any way to sync iDevices on Karmic,Jaunty and Hardy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone